# Passing addrinfo structure from child to parent using shared memory

Tags: c

I wanted to pass output of getaddrinfo structure (*res) into parent (from child) process using shared memory as below

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    .....
    iStatus = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &servinfoC);
    ...
    shmid = shmget(GETADDR_SHM_KEY, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    ....
    shmC = shmat(shmid, (void*)NULL, 0));
    memcpy(shmC, servinfoC, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    freeaddrinfo (servinfoC);
}
else
{
    struct addrinfo *servinfoP;
    while ((pid = waitpid (pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)) > 0)
    shmid = shmget(GETADDR_SHM_KEY, SHMSZ, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    shmP = shmat(shmid, (void*)NULL, 0));

    /*HELP Copy shmP to servinfoP struct*/

}
```

I tried memcpy but it didnt helped because of memory allocation required for addrinfo.

Thank you in advance for your time and help

Regards
Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to implement asynchronous DNS lookups with `fork`/processes, which is a *really really* bad idea. If you don't want an async DNS library, just use threads instead of `fork`. Then the resulting `struct addrinfo` is already in your program's address space and it can be used (and freed) by the caller.

The new thread should call `getaddrinfo` and inform the caller when it finishes; the method you use to inform the caller should depend on how your program's event handling works. Assuming it's single-threaded, you're probably using `select`/`poll` (or an abstraction thereof like `libevent`) so it may make sense for the thread to use a pipe that you can `select` on to indicate when the lookup is done.

P.S. Never use `shmget` etc. except for legacy interfaces (like X11) that require it. There are much cleaner more modern ways to do shared memory like `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS` (for anonymous shared memory that you'll only share with your `fork`ed children) or `shm_open` (POSIX named shared memory) or even `mmap` of ordinary files...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I exactly wanted to implement this.

Answer (score 5):

This will not work. The addrinfo struct contains pointers to other memory regions, and on top of that is a linked list of results. You will need to flatten it if you want to pass it though shared memory.

Eg:

```
struct addrinfo_flat
{
    int ai_family;
    int ai_socktype;
    int ai_protocol;
    struct sockaddr_storage ai_addr;
    socklen_t ai_addrlen;
};

struct addrinfo_flags *addrs = (struct addrinfo_flat*)shmC;
addrs->ai_family = ai->ai_family;
addrs->ai_socktype = ai->ai_socktype;
addrs->ai_protocol = ai->ai_protocol;
memcpy(&addrs->ai_addr, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen);
addrs->ai_addrlen = ai->ai_addrlen;
```

(multiple results left as an exercise)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the parent code to:

```
struct addrinfo servinfoP;
while ((pid = waitpid (pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)) > 0)
shmid = shmget(GETADDR_SHM_KEY, SHMSZ, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
shmP = shmat(shmid, (void*)NULL, 0));
memcpy(&servinfoP, shmP, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
```

Now you don't have to worry about space for `servinfoP` - of course if you want this to be available outside the current context, then you'll have to `malloc`

```
struct addrinfo* servinfoP = (struct addrinfo*) calloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo));
```

NOTE: this is all c not c++..

BTW. if you can guarantee that the shared memory segment will be available for the duration that you need the `addrinfo`, you could simply cast the pointer, e.g.

```
struct addrinfo* servinfoP = (struct addrinfo*) shmP;
```

Again, here you don't need a separate allocation...